# Unable to remove entity from unmanaged solution when exported

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to remove the Email entity from an unmanaged solution but on export the entity is added back into the solution and included as part of the export.

I can remove it from the solution fine, save and publish customizations and see that Email is no longer part of the solution.  However, when I export the solution irrespective of whether I perform another publish, the Email entity is been added back into the solution and gets included in the unmanaged export.  I can successfully remove PhoneCall and Task.

The only dependency on Email is from account which would be resolved on import as the target solution obviously contains Email.

Any ideas as to why I would be seeing this behaviour?  Assuming it's not a "feature" any suggestions on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to a Case Creation Rule.  We have a rule in the solution that creates the Case from Email and removing this custom rule prevents the reintroduction of the Email entity into the export.

I've reproduced this in a separate solution so I believe this is a bug in the new Case Creation Rules added in SP1.  I don't think you'd ever want entities being added to the export without your knowledge on export.  They should just be defined like all others as a missing dependency.